# Thousand of errors in base classes like NSObject.h,NSObjCRuntime.h

Tags: iphone

I don't know why its happening .... I an integrating a twitpic api and its working fine all the projects except one. I am getting 5488 errors and that too in classes like NSObject.h and NSObjCRuntime.h . This api has a folder named `Crypto` which has two .c files in it, when i remove this folder from my project then the error decreases to 1 (because one of the class from this folder is used else where).All 5k+ errors are in these two class only, errors are like

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT Class NSClassFromString(NSString *aClassName);
                         expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
```

few errors are

```
expected identifier or '(' before '@' token
expected identifier or '(' before '-' token
expected identifier or '(' before '+' token
```

One thing i am sure of is that there is no error in the classes because the same code is working good in other projects.
One more thing to mention is that I have two .pch and there is no effect of removing one of them.

Comment: I resolved the issue ..... what I was doing wrong is that I was importing one objective-C files outside { # ifdef __OBJC__  ... # endif } block in .pch file

Comment: can you explain in detail .i get same issye

Comment: @Srinivas in you .pch file you may be importing some objective-c file outside the #ifdef block and you may have some c files in the project.. just import your objective-c file inside that block

Comment: ya its absolutely right . i get  the result .but i have small doubt .with out complied c files how it will be used further.

Comment: Thanks for finding this!!  I was folding some sub-projects into a parent project and was getting hundreds of errors in Apple classes like NSString too.  It was a very o.O moment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

compile the files as objc, not c

Comment: I resolved the issue ..... what I was doing wrong is that I was importing one objective-C files outside { # ifdef OBJC  ... # endif } block in .pch file

Comment: All I had to do was change a .c at the end of one of my files to a .m and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Usually these errors are caused by a problem in the .pch file, like an #import that doesn't belong, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error several times. This could happen because of superfluous curly bracket. Like

```
- (void)a {
}
}
```

Check latest changes in a project.