# Getting errors in classes like NSObject.h,NSObjCRuntime.h while running tests in xcode

Tags: c, objective-c, xcode

I am currently writing a test class in objective c and in that class i am writing unit test cases for the c classes (old classes) that is there in the project.To do unit test i have imported the header file in the test class and in xcode i am able to acess those functions defined in that c class.

But when i try to run unit test cases then i am so many errors in the Foundation framework.

I have tried

- [Thousand of errors in base classes like NSObject.h,NSObjCRuntime.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295923/thousand-of-errors-in-base-classes-like-nsobject-h-nsobjcruntime-h)
- Renamed the .c class to .m which created a list of more errors.

Error I am getting in xcode 
[image: error]

I have been hitting my head for last couple of days to fix this !!. 
Can anyone have any suggestions or solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.c` files are treated as pure `C` files (in actuality `C++`) and presumably you are co-mingling `C` code with `Obj-C`.

By default, `C` and `C++` files will be set to be `Default - C++ Source`.

You have two choices.

You could rename the extensions of the offending files to `.mm`.

Alternatively to preserve the file name, go to File Inspector and change the type to `Objective C++ Source`. I'm showing you what it would look like. Note since this is a `.mm` file, it is automatically set to `Objective C++ Source`. Just set the `C` files to this type.

[image]